# SQL max() only returns 1 row if column has several max values

Tags: mysql, sql, max

This feels like a stupid question since it should have a simple answer, but I just can't find it. I have a table looking like this:

```
|-----|---|
|  a  | b |
|-----|---|
| ALA | 2 |
| ASP | 1 |
| SER | 1 |
| VAL | 2 |
|-----|---|
```

What I need is to get the two rows with the maximum value (I don't know the values in advance) which means that my example above shoud give:

```
|-----|--------|
|  a  | max(b) |
|-----|--------|
| ALA |   2    |
| VAL |   2    |
|-----|--------|
```

I'm trying

```
SELECT a, max(b) FROM table;
```

but it only gives the first maximum row:

```
|-----|--------|
|  a  | max(b) |
|-----|--------|
| ALA |   2    |
|-----|--------|
```

What do I miss?

Comment: `SELECT a, max(b) FROM table` should generate an error, as you used an aggregate function and missed the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: @RubensFarias, unfortunately MySQL allows this non-ANSI compliant syntax and users continually avail themselves of this at the detriment of their learning process and application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT a,b FROM table
WHERE b = (SELECT MAX(b) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable Y
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT Max(b) mB
       FROM YourTable
       ) M
On Y.b = M.mb
```

Also if you have sql server 2008+ / oracle you can use something like **[RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms176102(v=sql.120).aspx)**

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
       SELECT a, b, RANK() over (order by B DESC) rn
       FROM YourTable
     ) T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```

Comment: I think, that `TOP WITH TIES` is much simpler than `RANK` and more efficient.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Looks like you have a point, even when  I hear `WITH TIES` before still not very familiar with that one. Anyway OP didnt specify  Sql Server``  as rdbms, I just put it because came to my mind.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point that there is such option and it is rarely used, though it can be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server, you can use `TOP WITH TIES`, which should be more efficient than subquery or `RANK`.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES 
    a, b
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY b DESC;
```

Other databases may also have similar option.