# MySQL select MAX value from subquery only returns one results from outer query. Why?

Tags: mysql

(Using MariaDB 5.5
 *I am aware this is old but it's a 3rd party server I can't update it* )

I have a table of data with a date/year column. I need to list all the values based on a reference id but only with the most recent year.

Based on my recent question about subqueries I thought this was going to be a simple case of using a subquery with a `MAX()` selection, but that only ever returns one results. Why? And how do I get the full set of results.

## The table:

```
 create table ee_stats
(
    stat_id int(8) unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    ee_id smallint(6) unsigned null,
    ref_id int null comment 'external table reference.',
    date_year year null,
    value_counter int(8) unsigned null,
    value_percentage double(6,3) unsigned null 
)
```

## The data

```
stat_id | ee_id | ref_id | date_year | value_counter | value_percentage
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    301 |   32  |   14   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    302 |   32  |   1    |      2020 |      0        |         0
    303 |   32  |   21   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    304 |   32  |   22   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    305 |  464  |   17   |      2020 |      40       |         3
    306 |  464  |   18   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    307 |  464  |   20   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    308 |  464  |   2    |      2020 |      87       |        6.6
    309 |  464  |   19   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    310 |  464  |   7    |      2020 |      15       |        1.1
    311 |  464  |   10   |      2020 |      29       |        2.2
    312 |  464  |   11   |      2019 |      29       |        2.2
    313 |  464  |   16   |      2019 |      13       |        1.0
    314 |  464  |   7    |      2019 |     116       |        8.8
    315 |  464  |   19   |      2019 |      71       |        5.3
    316 |  464  |   4    |      2019 |      67       |         5
```

Intended result is to select all of the values with `ee_id = 464` and the most recent year on record (`2020`).

## My Query

```
SELECT es.stat_id, es.ee_id, es.ref_id, es.date_year, es.value_count,
       es.value_percentage, eed.descr
FROM ee_stats es
         LEFT JOIN ee_descriptor eed on es.ref_id = eed.id
WHERE es.ee_id = 464 AND es.date_year = (
    SELECT MAX(zz.date_year) FROM ee_stats zz WHERE zz.ee_id = es.ee_id
    )
```

But this only returns the first outer result:

> ```
>        305 |  464  |   17   |      2020 |      40       |         3
> ```

## My attempts

The subquery correctly returns the value `2020` when run independently (substituting the outer value). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027549/sql-max-only-returns-1-row-if-column-has-several-max-values) is very similar but that answer seems to be exactly what should be working here.

The works:

```
SELECT es.stat_id, es.ee_id, es.ref_id, es.date_year, es.value_count,
       es.value_percentage, eed.descr
FROM ee_stats es
         LEFT JOIN ee_descriptor eed on es.ref_id = eed.id
WHERE es.ee_id = 464 AND es.date_year = '2020'
```

And This works:

```
SELECT es.stat_id, es.ee_id, es.ref_id, es.date_year, es.value_count,
       es.value_percentage, eed.descr
FROM ee_stats es
         LEFT JOIN ee_descriptor eed on es.ref_id = eed.id
WHERE es.ee_id = 464 AND es.date_year = (
    SELECT MAX(zz.date_year) FROM ee_stats zz WHERE zz.ee_id = '464'
    )
```

but somehow the dynamic outer reference to the `ee_id` value only returns one result on the SQL.

## Intended result:

```
    305 |  464  |   17   |      2020 |      40       |         3
    306 |  464  |   18   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    307 |  464  |   20   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    308 |  464  |   2    |      2020 |      87       |        6.6
    309 |  464  |   19   |      2020 |      0        |         0
    310 |  464  |   7    |      2020 |      15       |        1.1
    311 |  464  |   10   |      2020 |      29       |        2.2
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, please have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cc105/2)

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos my only thought it maybe it's an issue with being on MariaDb rather than MySQL?

Comment: Your query looks good.

Comment: This should be ok for MariaDb as well

Comment: I found the problem is fixed by casting the `MAX` output to being a date format. I don't know why or how this is an issue, but I think MAX maybe was silently converting it to something else.

Comment: Works in MariabDB 10.3. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4e7c7ae749ba8006e9b2ade936e6e17f

Comment: @TheImpaler yes sadly I have to work on 5.5 `:-/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I found I had to CAST the MAX entity to being the correct format; so I had to cast it to a DATE format.

```
CAST(MAX(zz.date_year) AS DATE)
```

This works.

```
SELECT es.stat_id, es.ee_id, es.ref_id, es.date_year, es.value_count,
       es.value_percentage, eed.descr
FROM ee_stats es
         LEFT JOIN ee_descriptor eed on es.ref_id = eed.id
WHERE es.ee_id = 464 AND es.date_year = (
    SELECT CAST(MAX(zz.date_year) AS DATE) FROM ee_stats zz WHERE zz.ee_id = es.ee_id
    )
```